# Editing models which are not Tree/Table/List-based in QT4/PySide?

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, qt4, pyside

The Qt documentation makes a big deal about the model/view framework, but it seems like it only supports models that inherit from `QAbstractItemModel` - i.e. things like tables, lists, and trees. What about other types of models (as in the general concept of the MVC pattern)?

In my specific case, the user is entering the inputs and parameters for a bioinformatics tool. In JSON, the data I want may look something like this:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/file1.fasta",
            "format": "fasta",
            "compression": null
        },
        {
            "path": "/path/to/file2.fastq",
            "format": "fastq",
            "compression": "gzip"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "taxonomy_database_id": 1,
    "reference_signatures_set": "my_signatures_set",
    "results_per_file": 5,
    ...
}
```

The `files` property fits well into Qt's model system - I use some sort of `QAbstractTableModel` with three columns, create a `QTableView` for viewing it, and add a button that shows a `QFileDialog` with some logic to add rows to it.

The rest of the properties don't fit the Qt model framework well. There's no order to them, the values are non-homogeneous, and I need to be able to access them by name. There's only one instance of this model, so there's not much reason to stick it into a table like I did with the files.

There's nothing special about my exact model, it's the same problem with a user entering their personal info:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "zip_code": 12345,
}
```

In both my case and the example I might want to connect to a signal that notifies me of changes, then run some validation logic. However these are not just generic "items", there is specific logic for each one - for example checking the zip code to see if the user is within range of a service or checking if the user is a minor. It makes much more sense for the code to be checking the return value of `model.getZipCode()` rather than `model.data(model.index(2, 0))`.

The data storage and business logic are easily implemented by subclassing `QObject` and implementing all properties as Qt properties. However, it becomes a pain to set up views for this. Qt doesn't seem to have any built-in view classes for it. I can create a form widget for editing without much of a problem, but two-way data bindings between object properties and `QComboBox` and the like is difficult out of the box.

If I instead implement the model as a `QAbstractItemModel` with one column and properties in rows, I can create views and editors very easily. It is especially easy to use a `QDataWidgetMapper` to connect to the editor widgets in my form. The model updates when the user edits a widget, and the view updates when I reset the model to default or load a saved configuration. But then to work with this model I have to use `QModelIndex` and rows and columns for everything, which are meaningless with regards to the actual semantics of the model. This makes the business logic much more difficult and messy.

The solution I have come up with is just a proxy `QAbstractListModel` which sits between the real model and the views, but this seems unnecessarily complex. This is why I am confused and feel like I have missed something major in the documentation or examples.

Comment: If you are not using the view widgets provided by Qt, then you don't need to care about Qt model/view framework. Just write your own view for your own kind of model, shouldn't be too hard. If you do want to use view widgets which use Qt's models, then you should create a model, which provides the data you want using the Qt model interface. For example a model which provides properties of a QObject as 2-column table shouldn't be very complicated. Could you clarify what you want, exactly?

Comment: Perhaps looking at these classes will help you to clarify what you mean, and give you ideas: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractproxymodel.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html

Comment: @hyde - I believe you are correct that I simply need to make my own model classes. It's certainly do-able, but it seems surprising to me that Qt requires you to either shoehorn all your data into table format or create your own view classes for it. It definitely seems possible to make some very generic view classes that work for all key/value or property-based models. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a more standard solution in the documentation.

Comment: With your update this has become even more of a [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). What problem do you want to actually solve, and what did you try using Qt, and why did that not work out (or you think it didn't)?

Comment: I believe this problem is a very general one, but I have added some specific examples that should hopefully make the problem more clear.

Comment: Just write your own model. You don't need any Qt specific model. Why would you?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're mixing up some concepts here.

1. The Qt model views depend on `QAbstractItemModel` because they need the interface to access the model data. They simply can't use a `QObject` that doesn't provide this interface.

   Additional Hint: `QAbstractItemModel` derives from `QObject`.
2. > just a set of named fields or key-value pairs

   That is, in fact, a list or table structure, depending on whether you have one or (at least) two columns. What do you expect "other types of models" to look like?
3. For simple models you can derive from `QAbstractListModel` or `QAbstractTableModel`, or perhaps even use `QStringListModel` or `QStandardItemModel`; the first two have most, the latter all of the abstract methods implemented for these standard cases.
4. > The model itself is easy enough to create as a QObject with some properties.

   It is up to you to implement a model that uses `QObject` properties for data, if you think it's the way to go for some reason. But for most cases this is an unnecessary layer of indirection, IMO.

Comment: I reformatted my question to hopefully make it more clear, but I think you just answered it with point #1. Qt just expects everything to be put in a table or tree of some sort. It's definitely possible with the two-column model you described, but then it just makes it more difficult to use from the rest of my code. For example I want to monitor when `mymodel.myProperty` changes, not when item `(4, 1)` changes. It seems like creating a `QAbstractItemModel` adapter class or custom view class are my only real options.

Comment: @JaredL Keep in mind that Qt is, after all, a C++ framework, and restricted to the data and type models available in that language, despite the awesome work the Python bindings are providing. If you want something completely pythonic, you may have to stay with modules originally implemented in Python. So I tend to think you're hitting the barriers of Python vs. C++ here, but I don't understand, less than before your update, what you're looking for, and an actual example of what you want to achieve would really be helpful, as hyde was already pointing out.

Comment: I really don't think it is a C++ vs Python problem, it's more about the model structure and semantics not fitting the "Item Model" mold well. I have added some specific examples that don't have anything to do with Python, which I hope should make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a model isn't the right data structure for your problem. However, take a look at Qt Designer and its [representation of object properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-widget-mode.html#the-property-editor).

Regarding `QModelIndex`, it is just a token passed around to map a cell in the view to data from the model identified by a three-dimensional address consisting of parent, row and column. You can add an integer (usually a list index) or pointer (make that `id()` in Python) for convenient mapping to source objects, but the three dimensions should fit the data from your example quite nicely.

The MVC implementation of Qt surely isn't straightforward, and the learning curve is a bit steep, but when you've mastered the concept behind it it's a mighty tool. Keep going!